# Finding area inside circle and outside another circle

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, area

I was trying to find the area inside the circle $r=-2\cos(\theta)$ and outside $r=1$ and the upper bound was $2\pi/3$ while the lower bound is $0$. Is this correct?  If not please help me set this up. Thanks.

Comment: I presume 'r' is radius. What angle is being referred to as $\theta $?

Comment: This is very similar to [another question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747025/explain-finding-the-area-of-a-region). You need to sketch the relevant graphs. If you are unskilled at this, use a grapher, such as the free online [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/).

Comment: @Benedict theta is 2 pi/3 while the second circles equation is r = 1

Comment: @imranfat i have only figured out one point after graphing the curves, which is 2pi/3. Not quite sure how to get the second one.

Comment: Would be good to find out how to embed a 'Desmos' graph into either a question or an answer. How is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that the curves intersect when $\cos(\theta)=-\dfrac{1}{2}$ which is at $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$. But because of symmetry with respect to the horizontal axis you could just double the area between $\theta=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\theta=\pi$. And as long as we are using symmetry, the area is the same as that lying outside $r=1$ and inside $r=2\cos\theta$ so why not just find and double the area of the region between the rays $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ and $\theta=0$ inside the curve $r=2\cos\theta$ and $r=1$?
\begin{equation}
A=2\int_0^{\pi/3}\frac{1}{2}\left(4\cos^2\theta-1\right)\,d\theta
\end{equation}

Comment: Note: to complete the integral I am assuming you already know the power reduction identity $\cos^2\theta=\dfrac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2}$

Comment: I have tried your solution and this is what I have come up with, is the answer correct? http://imgur.com/CmyK8wi

Comment: No, you've gotten the limits wrong. The integral which I gave is actually using the reflection in the $y$-axis of the original problem and then taking twice the integral between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{3}$. Otherwise, we would have to take twice the integral between $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\pi$ which would give the same result but be slightly messier. The fact that you got a negative answer for an area should have been a clue that something was not right. If you use the limits $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{3}$ you will get the correct answer which is the negative of the answer which you got.

Comment: Follow a link to the fooplot.com graph. This is actually the graph or $r=1$ and $r=2\cos\theta$ which is your problem reflected about the $y$-axis. I had to put in a scale factor of $\frac{6}{5}$ because fooplot does not scale the two axes equally for some strange reason. Otherwise the circles look like ellipses.You are finding the area of the crescent region on the right between the lines $y=\pm\sqrt{3}x$ since $\tan\frac{\pi}{3}=\sqrt{3}$.  http://fooplot.com/plot/mt6n19ygtz